# I want to increase the length of the snake by eating each piece

Tags: c#, console-application

When the snake swallows the prey, the IncreaseLen5 method is activated, which, as you can see, follows the IncreaseLen method, which has the task of adding a house to the end of the snake. But nothing happens. Why?
Thank you for your help.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.CursorVisible = false;
    InitSnakePoints();
    CreateHook();

    while (true)
    {
        DrawSnake();
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        ChangeDirection();
        MoveSnake();

        if (IsFindHook()) //<-------here
        {
            IncreaseLen5();
            CreateHook();
        }
    }
}

private static void IncreaseLen5()
{
    for (int i=0;   i<5;  i++)
    IncreaseLen();
}

private static void IncreaseLen()
{
    snakeX[snakeLen] = snakeX[snakeLen - 1];
    snakeY[snakeLen] = snakeY[snakeLen - 1];
}

private static bool IsFindHook()
{
    if (snakeX[0] == hookX)
        if (snakeY[0] == hookY)
            return true;
    return false;
}
     
private static void CreateHook()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int x = random.Next(0, Console.WindowWidth  -1);
    int y = random.Next(0, Console.WindowHeight -1);

    hookX = x;
    hookY = y;

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
    Console.Write(snakeHook);

}
```

Comment: hard to tell what's going on without the complete code

Comment: What is snakeX and how is it defined?

Comment: You need to use a queue : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)

Answer (score 1):

The problems I see:

- You are tracking the coordinates of the snake in two arrays for x and y. I assume their sizes are 5, but when you increase the length of your snake, you have to increase the size of the array as well, which you can't. It would be better to use two lists instead, where you can `Add()` the new coordinates. The shuffling of the coordinates in `MoveSnake()` should probably work like the same.
- When increasing the length you are "stacking" the same coordinates. Let's say `snakeX[snakeLen - 1]` is 8, then your are adding 8 five times to `snakeX`. When moving your snake to the left for one field, all these values become 7. Drawing the snake will result in printing 5 dots at the same coordinates which looks like one. A solution could be storing the position of the snake's end, move it one field and then extend the list of x and y. This has to be done 5 times.